# How do I change my element's background color?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to change the background color of a div I have in my HTML, here is what I have so far:

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="center-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="right-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.footer {
  color: #FF0000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `color` is the text color. Did you want `background-color`? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/az3yLf75/

Comment: yes but I have tried background-color and it still doesn't work

Comment: Does your footer have content or a height? See my fiddle.

Comment: Since your rep is so low I did not want to down vote but you seem to ask a lot of simple questions looking for answers to all your coding issues. Please try to do more research first before opening new questions.

Comment: Is this really all the HTML and CSS you have? There's no content or text of any kind in your divs?

Comment: Perhaps he has an !important set somewhere?

Can you inspect the element in the Chrome inspector?  Right click the page on the element you want, (footer), click inspect element and on the right side take a snapshot of the styles and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably after something like this:

```
.footer {
    color: #FF0000;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You'll also need some content in the actual div's to see the background colour, or set height/padding

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `background` (shorthand) or `background-color` to change the background color.

Something like this would:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You'll also need to add either something to the div to give it height, or declare at height for the div in CSS like so:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Ha sorry this appeared after I submitted mine, they are eerily similar...

Comment: Well... looks like everyone decided to answer at once.

Comment: I have tried using background-color and it doesn't work

Comment: @Andeb-autos make sure the child DIVs of `.footer` are not empty. If all your DIVs are empty they will have no height.

Comment: they are not empty, one is full

Comment: Can you post your complete code so we can take a look at it?

Comment: @Andeb-autos are you suggesting that `.footer` is full? And I'm asking this based on the markup you supplied in your question. If so, then no, `.footer` is not full. It might have DIVs in it, but those DIVs have no height therefore `.footer` has no height.

Answer (score 0):

You may need background-color, instead of color. Color is normally for font color

Comment: I have tried using background-colour and it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried putting something in the div? For instance https://jsfiddle.net/85oxug8f/

Comment: If there is nothing in the div and no height declared you'll not see anything.

Comment: i have something in my div

Comment: @Andeb-autos are you suggesting that `.footer` is full? And I'm asking this based on the markup you supplied in your question. If so, then no, `.footer` is not full. It might have DIVs in it, but those DIVs have no height therefore `.footer` has no height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CSS` property of

```
background-color
```

*This adds color to the background of the selected element*

The property (`color`) which you have used adds *color to the foreground to the selected element i.e. it represents the color of the text*

```css
.footer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;    /*Added just for demonstration purpose*/
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="center-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="right-footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work

Comment: Run the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property changes the text color.  You need to set the `background-color` property instead.  However, unless you give the `div` some height you won't be able to see it!

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="center-footer">
  </div>
  <div class="right-footer">
  </div>
</div>

.footer {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CSS you are using the incorrect property to set the background color, use `background-color` instead of `color`. `color` is used for setting the color of you text.

**Note** Based on some comments to answers it seems that you have tested `background-color` on your sample markup, which has no content and therefore the DIVs will have no height and you will not see the background color. Please add content to the DIVs or give them a specified height so you can see `background-color` working.

```css
.footer {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Another possibility (based on unseen code and assumed code) is that the child DIVs of `.footer` are all floated, causing the `.footer` DIV to collapse and hide the background color. To fix this you would need to apply a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to the `.footer` DIV.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use background-color. color is for text

```
.footer {
       background-color: the color you want;
}
```